# Optimizing recursive dot replacement R function

Tags: r, recursion

Let's say you are producing nested list structures, sometimes they have dots in the element names and sometimes they don't. The issue with that is we need to convert these nested lists to JSON and insert them into a mongo collection. I currently have the following function that does this but it is extremely slow for deeply nested structures. I'm trying to figure out how to speed this up by an order of magnitude if possible. TIA!

```
substituteDotNotation <- function(x) {

  if(class(x) %in% c("list","data.frame")) {
    
    if(class(x) %in% c("list")) {
      
      if(!is.empty(x) || length(x) %in% seq(1,1000000,1)) {
        
        if(!is.empty(names(x))) {
          
          names(x) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(x))
          
        }
        
      }
      
    } else if(nrow(x) > 0) {
      
      names(x) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(x))
      
    }
    
    if(class(x) %in% c("list")) {
      
        x <- lapply(x,substituteDotNotation)
        
      } else {
        
        return(x)
      }
    
  } else {
    
    return(x)
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: `length(x) %in% seq(1,1000000,1))` this looks funny to me

Comment: That's how I roll /shrug